RestTemplate.exchange is working but FeignClient is not
I am calling a third party api and the request using feignClient gives 400 Bad request error
public interface NameMatchClient {

    @PostMapping("/v1/name/match")
    ResponseEntity<NameMatchResponseDto> matchNames(
            @RequestBody NameMatchRequestDto nameMatchRequestDto
    );

}

feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400 Bad Request] during [POST] to [https://demo.com/v1/name/match] [NameMatchClient#matchNames(NameMatchRequestDto)]: [{"data": null, "message": "Bad Request Error", "status": "error"}]    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:213)  at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)
Whereas while using restTemplate, I am getting back response successfully.

            MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            formData.add("pan_name", aadhaarName);
            formData.add("pan_name_combined", aadhaarName);
            formData.add("bank_name", bgvName);

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(formData, headers);

            ResponseEntity<NameMatchResponseDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://demo.com/v1/name/match", HttpMethod.POST, entity, NameMatchResponseDto.class);

what is the reason behind this behaviour?

Show us NameMatchRequestDto.

`public class NamematchRequestDto {
private String name1;
private String name2;
private String name3;
}`

Show full stack trace. I don't understand why Feign is involved.
